# Why does "git push heroku master" upload all my data and not only the changes?

Tags: git, heroku

When I push my changes to github it only pushes the changes. A few kBs.

```
git push origin
```

When I push the same changes to heroku.

```
git push heroku master
```

It uploads all the data, 35MBs in my case. Why is this? And what can I do about it?

Comment: How are you measuring the amount uploaded?

Comment: The commands tell me how much is uploaded: 
Writing objects: 100% (61/61), 560.95 KiB, done.
Writing objects: 100% (6133/6133), 35.73 MiB, done.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data transferred by `git push` depends on the state of the local and remote branches.  What happens if you `git push heroku master` again?  If there have been no changes to your local branch since the last push, the transfer should be much smaller.

Comment: That's true, if there is no change at all the heroku push will say everything is up to date, but when I make the slightest change it uploads the complete thing again.